# Magento2: How to temporarily disable "update on save" when saving products programatically?

Tags: magento2, indexing, programmatically

I have a CLI command on my module that runs through the products collection & updates some of the attributes.
I noticed that it's extremely slow. Each save() takes about 4-5 seconds, which is a lot when you have thousands...
My first guess was that it happens because some of the indexers are set to 'Update on save' (correct me if I'm wrong).

1. Is there any way to tell Magento to skip the indexing until the process is done & then reindex all at once?
2. If it's not the indexers then what else could it be?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: No, I had to change my code in order to avoid saving the products during the process.

Answer (score 1):

Oy,

I know it is old and might be optimized already. But if you only updating attribute values only, it is a little overshoot to save the whole product.

Please see

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action::updateAttributes

```
public function updateAttributes($entityIds, $attrData, $storeId)
```

example:

```
$this->_updateAction->updateAttributes(
    $productId,
    [
        'attribute_name_1' => value,
        'attribute_name_2' => value,
        ...
    ],
    $storeId
);
```

as indexers, you can check if the attributes required to index as

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attribute */
$attribute->isIndexable()
```

and trigger EAV indexer

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Eav\Processor $productEavIndexerProcessor */
$productEavIndexerProcessor->reindexList(array_unique($productIds)))
```

If you amending product-category connection, you might be required to run

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category $categoryIndexer */
$categoryIndexer->reindexList(array_unique($productIds));
```

as well

attribute save happening directly to DB (that why it is required to handle indexer manually)

---

I know the whole process (with indexer) available as

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action::updateAttributes

but if you need to set different attribute values for different products it cannot be used as calling this method will reindex automatically over and over again and you will facing performance issues again

Answer (score 0):

I solved that using temporary lock file and this code:

```
namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category as IndexerCategory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Processor;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;
use Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry;

class ReindexLock
{
    const LOCK_FILE = 'reindex.assignment.lock';

    /**
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryList;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @var IndexerRegistry
     */
    protected $indexerRegistry;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $reindexIsScheduledStatus = [];

    protected $indexes = [
        IndexerCategory::INDEXER_ID,
        Product::INDEXER_ID,
        Processor::INDEXER_ID,
        STATE::INDEXER_ID,
        Fulltext::INDEXER_ID
    ];

    public function __construct(
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry,
        DirectoryList $directoryList,
        File $file
    ) {
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->file = $file;

        $path = $this->directoryList->getPath('var') . '/tmp';

        if (false === is_dir($path)) {
            $this->file->mkdir($path, 0775);
        }

        $this->file->open(['path' => $path]);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        if (count($this->reindexIsScheduledStatus) > 0) {
            foreach ($this->indexes as $index) {
                if (true === isset($this->reindexIsScheduledStatus[$index])) {
                    if (false === $this->reindexIsScheduledStatus[$index]) {
                        $productCategoryIndexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get($index);
                        $productCategoryIndexer->setScheduled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->file->rm(self::LOCK_FILE);
    }

   /**
    * @return ReindexLock
    * @throws \Exception
    */
    public function changeReindexMode(): ReindexLock
    {
        if (true === $this->file->fileExists(self::LOCK_FILE)) {
            throw new \Exception("The process is already in running.\n");
        }

        if (0 === count($this->reindexIsScheduledStatus)) {
            $this->file->write(self::LOCK_FILE, '', 0666);

                foreach ($this->indexes as $index) {
                    $productCategoryIndexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get($index);
                    $this->reindexIsScheduledStatus[$index] = $productCategoryIndexer->isScheduled();

                    if ($this->reindexIsScheduledStatus[$index] === false) {
                        $productCategoryIndexer->setScheduled(true);
                    }
                }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The idea of lock file is to avoid parallel processes which can bring collisions with reindex mode. It saves the current mode state, then temporary sets its to "on schedule" mode and then put it back to the original one.

I'm not sure if it's ok to use it as a not-singleton class.

Answer (score -1):

You can set indexer mode using command

```
bin/magento indexer:set-mode [mode]
```

here you can specify mode '**realtime**' for Update on save, '**schedule**' Update by Schedule.
For example following command set '**Category Products**' and '**Product Categories**' Update by Schedule.

```
bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule catalog_category_product catalog_product_category
```

View more on [magento doc](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html)

Comment: Not relevant to the question.

Answer (score -2):

When you save a product and you've got your indexers configured as "save on update" the indexer will have to reindex after every save obviously. The other downside to this configuration is that when your catalog will grow the time to index will grow with it.

I think the best approach will be to set indexers to "reindex on schedule" which can be achieved by running the following cli command:

```
bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime
```

Make sure you've got the Magento cron installed otherwise indexers will never update (installation command below).

```
bin/magento cron:install
```

Or to run the cron manually

```
bin/magento cron:run
```

Comment: I know all that. My question was about *temporarily* disabling the 'update on save' (programatically) & then set it back after the process is done. (*Although it's recommended to set the indexers to 'update by schedule', the module I'm working on might be installed on a lot of websites & some of them might be  configured differently & it's not my place, as an extension builder to change their settings)